# Format item text in Dojo/Digit ComboBox

Tags: javascript, dojo

Say I have the following text in a ComboBox:

Sponsor: Project Title

Is it possible to just make Sponsor: bold? I can make the whole thing bold by adding the following to the CSS:

```
.dijitMenuItem {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```

But not sure how to do it for only part of the text. Is there something similar to the formatter method for a datagrid? Thanks for any help!

Here is a link to the actual site:
http://webmap.psrc.org/Transportation/2015-2018TIP.html

Comment: In the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7on1e3h8/2/ I've set the labels as HTML, but I can't do the same trick with the input (because there's the 'value' set, not the 'innerHTML').

Comment: Thanks! I'll see if I can get that to work.